# How can I put app code on GitHub from RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I wrote an app in `golem` framework with many modules and other components. I would like to send all my code to repository on GitHub. I read that I'd have to upload app's code on Gist first as to others could see it on GitHub. I have GitHub account and  I wouldn't like to upload code manually on Gist, is there any way to do it from RStudio level? And sorry for this question if it seems too easy but it's the very first time I upload R code on GitHub.

Comment: Does [this](https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-git-github.html) help?

Comment: I'll take a look;)